# Invoking glossaries to fill author field of bib entries

Tags: biblatex, glossaries

It doesn't work out of the box: it's treats first and last name as last name. I guess "expand after" comes into play, but long time since I used this feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  in = {dans},
}

\newglossary*{cont}{Contact}

\newglossaryentry{dupont}
{
  type=cont,
  name={Dupont, Michel},
  description={}
}    

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lefoo
  ,author =       {Dupond, Marie}
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
@article{lebar
  ,author =       {\gls{dupont}}
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Une citation: \autocite{lefoo}.

Une citation au milieu du texte: Comme \textcite{lebar} a dit \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Print]

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. By the time biblatex gets access to the author, the bib file has been processed by biber and the author name has been broken apart. You could potentially hack the data model to replace things ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this simply won't work.

Name fields need to be parsed by Biber (or BibTeX) to extract the different name parts (given name, family name, suffix and prefix), since Biber does not know about LaTeX macros in general (it knows about some macros for single non-ASCII characters) there is no way `\gls{dupont}` would be treated like `Dupont, Michel`.

In the example `\gls{dupont}` is treated as the sole family name of the author and the macro is only later expanded to produce the output you see.

There are no amounts of `\expandafter` s that could help you to pass the expected name to Biber. You could use a source map to replace the macro again, but that appears a bit backwards and you lose all other benefits of `\gls`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  in = {dans},
}

\newglossary*{cont}{Contact}

\newglossaryentry{dupont}
{
  type=cont,
  name={Dupont, Michel},
  description={}
}    

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\\gls\{dupont\}}, replace={Dupont, Michel}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lefoo
  ,author =       {Dupond, Marie}
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
@article{lebar
  ,author =       {\gls{dupont}}
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Une citation: \autocite{lefoo}.

Une citation au milieu du texte: Comme \textcite{lebar} a dit \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Correctly formatted names.]

You probably need a different way to achieve what you want to do with `\gls`.

Comment: I feel like with some nasty expandafter and regexp trickery you might be able to match all `\gls{*}` and make the "replace" be essentially `\expandafter\gls{*}`, but it is so not worth it.

Comment: @StrongBad Nice idea. The replacement text is accessible expandably in `\glo@<label>@name`. But I couldn't get this to work since I would need Biber to match the regexp in `\gls{.*}` and then pass the captured group back to LaTeX to resolve `\glo@$1@name`.

Comment: At a minimum you could change `replace={Dupont, Michel}` to something like `replace={\glo@dupont@name}` with a whole bunch of expandafter trickery to get `\glo@dupont@name` to actually be expanded.

Comment: @StrongBad True `replace={\csname glo@dupont@name\endcsname}` would work, but might explode when you have non-ASCII chars in non Unicode-engines, so finer expansion control is needed.