# Changing appearance of hyperlinks locally

Tags: hyperref

The code below is borrowed from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks). Sol #1: I expected `foo` to be highlighted, it isn't. Since I want the change to be local anyway, how would I restore the defaults?

```
\documentclass[oneside,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thisfbshare}{}{\href{https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php}{\faFacebookSquare}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\thistwshare}{}{\href{http://foo.com/?share=twitter\&nb=1}{\faTwitterSquare}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\thisshare}{}{\thisfbshare\thistwshare}

\begin{document}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks

% SOL # 1
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}

% SOL # 2
%\hypersetup{
%    colorlinks=false,
%    pdfborder={0 0 0},
%}

{\large Don't forget to share on \thisshare~for \href{http://foo.com}{foo}}

%HOW TO RESTORE?

\end{document}
```

PS: the surrounding boxes for FB and Tw would be just fine if they didn't overlap with each other.

[image: Print]
[image: Print]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colorlinks option must be set in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[oneside,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thisfbshare}{}{\href{https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php}{\faFacebookSquare}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\thistwshare}{}{\href{http://foo.com/?share=twitter\&nb=1}{\faTwitterSquare}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\thisshare}{}{\thisfbshare\thistwshare}

\begin{document}

{\large Don't forget to share on \thisshare~for \href{http://foo.com}{foo}}

\hypersetup{
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}

{\large Don't forget to share on \thisshare~for \href{http://foo.com}{foo}}

\hypersetup{allcolors=black,pdfborder=0 0 1}

{\large Don't forget to share on \thisshare~for \href{http://foo.com}{foo}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just one problem: calls to `\gls` within body of text get highlighted. See setup [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508979/invoking-glossaries-to-fill-author-field-of-bib-entries). I guess [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73762/one-way-links-to-glossaries#73768) is the answer?

Comment: Related question, how to retrieved `hypersetup` parameters, such as `urlcolor`?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments.  That pings only one person. Ask a new question.